# Setup.exe not working or slow to open install dialog for a ClickOnce application

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

I am trying to use ClickOnce to automatically update a C# software.

I can publish my application, the setup.exe is created, but when I download/run it, windows tells me that application can be dangerous, the publisher cannot be verified. And if I choose to run it anyway, or as administrator, the install dialog sometimes appear after 10 min but in general nothing happen.

I tried to find a way to make my application trustful but even if :

- I enable ClickOnce security settings
- Select "This is a full trust application" in "Security"
- Add a certificate in "Signing"

It is still not working, so I have no more idea about how to fix this.

I can install it with the ".application" file but I think that is not the correct way to do it.

Thanks by advance !

Comment: Are you deploying this as an enterprise app (you have a domain controller, cert server, active directory)?  If not, please describe your IT environment (because the "best" solution depends on your resources)

Comment: Yes, I am deploying this as an enterprise app.
It's sad to say that but I am an intern, it's the first time I have to do this and no one can help me because they don't have "permanent IT guy" but only interns. 
They don't have windows server so, no DC, no AD and I don't know cert server but I guess it's the same.
Honestly, if you can give me a "normal answer", like the best way to do this even if I can't and a "working answer" which is not the best but will work, that would be perfect. Because this app will only be used in intern and the company don't care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close.  Much of the slowness is probably because of anti-virus.  Signing it will make things better.  The client machines will complain about how trustworthy the app is, unless you install your key (the one used for signing) on each of their machines.

Installing with the ".application" is just fine, especially if you are installing from a network share (instead of a web site or intranet site).  That should put an app (icon) in the users' start menu.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For this time I will use the ".application" then, it will be easier and make me save time.
But I am also working on a personal project, a video game, and I would like to create a launcher to check for updates. 
I think that ClickOnce could be a good way to make it. 
The launcher is updated if I make updates and then it update my game, because I am using Unity, I think that I can't directly use ClickOnce on my game, so I have to create my own "checking for update" software.

Comment: That sounds slick, but keep-in-mind that ClickOnce can be tricky because lots of evil folks use it to install viruses. So anti-virus is super wary of click-once apps.  Just be prepared to go-big with the signing and certificates and stuff.